# Aggregate function in R converting columns to Factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with some numeric columns, some factor columns, and some character columns. I've created df as a representation. When I try to use "aggregate" to collapse this data frame against the "PO.Line" column, it converts all of my columns to factors. Why is this?

As a side note, if my data frame does not include the Customer.Name column, aggregate appears to work fine.

```
df
  Order.Number PO.Line Unit.Selling.Price       Agreement Shipped Customer.Name
1            1     A_1                 10                       1           One
2            3     A_1                  0                      NA           two
3            4     A_2                 15 Platinum Member      NA          bill
4            7     A_2                  0                       1       craster
5            8     B_3                 12                       3       marilyn

str(df)
# 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ Order.Number      : num  1 3 4 7 8
# $ PO.Line           : Factor w/ 3 levels "A_1","A_2","B_3": 1 1 2 2 3
# $ Unit.Selling.Price: num  10 0 15 0 12
# $ Agreement         : Factor w/ 2 levels "","Platinum Member": 1 1 2 1 1
# $ Shipped           : num  1 NA NA 1 3
# $ Customer.Name     : chr  "One" "two" "bill" "craster" ...

str(aggregate(. ~ PO.Line, data = df, head, 1))
# 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ PO.Line           : Factor w/ 3 levels "A_1","A_2","B_3": 1 2 3
#  $ Order.Number      : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","7","8": 1 2 3
#  $ Unit.Selling.Price: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","10","12": 2 1 3
#  $ Agreement         : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1
#  $ Shipped           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 2
#  $ Customer.Name     : Factor w/ 3 levels "craster","marilyn",..: 3 1 2

df$Customer.Name <- NULL
str(aggregate(. ~ PO.Line, data = df, head, 1))
# 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ PO.Line           : Factor w/ 3 levels "A_1","A_2","B_3": 1 2 3
#  $ Order.Number      : num  1 7 8
#  $ Unit.Selling.Price: num  10 0 12
#  $ Agreement         : num  1 1 1
#  $ Shipped           : num  1 1 3
```

Comment: Suspect default `simplify=TRUE` with `head` as your function is not what you want.

Comment: I suggest you use `library(data.table)` or `library(dplyr)`. Aggregate is both slow and aggravating to use in my opinion.